# Excel doesn't apply mso-number-format from HTML

Tags: html, excel, formatting, cell

Here is my situation: I have [simple Excel OOXML file](http://www.filedropper.com/excel_1) with Web Query connection to my server. All cells with dates have "General" horizontal alignment (no alignment) and MM/DD/YYYY format. It looks like this:

[image: Before refresh]

On refresh server responses with pretty straightforward HTML:

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
   <head>
      <style id="Leads_style">
        table
        {
            mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
            mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";
        } 
        .cs0 { mso-number-format:\@; }
        .cs1 { mso-number-format:mm\/dd\/yyyy; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="tbl_0_Leads" x:publishsource="Excel">
         <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="white-space:nowrap">Leads</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td align="left" colspan="2">27 Aug 2014 08:02 AM +0:00 GMT</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="tbl_3_Leads" x:publishsource="Excel">
         <tr>
            <td>Display Name</td>
            <td>Created Date</td>
            <td>Last Modified Date</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="cs0" x:str="Darrow Mag, Mrs.">Darrow Mag, Mrs.</td>
            <td class="cs1">04/23/2009</td>
            <td class="cs1">08/06/2014</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="cs0" x:str="q q, Prof.">q q, Prof.</td>
            <td class="cs1">06/04/2014</td>
            <td class="cs1">08/06/2014</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="cs0" x:str="dasd dsa, Dr.">dasd dsa, Dr.</td>
            <td class="cs1">06/16/2014</td>
            <td class="cs1">08/06/2014</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="cs0" x:str="Bouat Jerome, Dr.">Bouat Jerome, Dr.</td>
            <td class="cs1">08/12/2014</td>
            <td class="cs1">08/12/2014</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Notice that .cs1 class in style section has `mso-number-format:mm\/dd\/yyyy`, so all dates in Excel document should look like `08/27/2014`.

For unknown reason, Excel applies wrong format (`MM.DD.YYYY`) to date cells:
[image: After refresh]

Two cells that seem normal also have `MM.DD.YYYY` format, but Excel shows them as `MM/DD/YYYY` with left alignment because DD value is much more than maximum of MM value (yeah, that's really weird too).

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The correct mso-number-format code for this would be `mso-number-format:"mm\\/dd\\/yyyy"`. But this is not the whole solution. If Excel reads HTML, then it gets the values as if the user would enter these values into the cell. If you enter 08/06/2014 in a cell, which date value is then created?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I enter 08/06/2014 in a cell, 08/06/2014 is created. I've also tried `mm\\/dd\\/yyyy` format, all cells in Excel have `MM/DD/YYYY` format now, but it [looks like this](http://s13.postimg.org/phvijzbgn/Untitled.png). Notice the difference in format between two dates in editor.

Comment: Are you sure the 08/06/2014, you have entered, is stored as MM/DD/YYYY? Not DD/MM/YYYY? But anyway: HTML is a format for data presentation. It is often not useable for data exchange. A good format for data exchange is XML, because it is easy to transform into HTML. But also in XML we must adhere to conventions. A good convention for date values is the ISO format YYYY-MM-DD. So for data exchange use this format and transform it, if needed, into other formats for data presentation.

Comment: I've checked again, you're right: 08/06/2014 is stored as 08.06.2014 according to the system locale (dd.mm.yyyy). ISO format YYYY-MM-DD with `mso-number-format:"mm\\/dd\\/yyyy"` works perfect! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found the solution.

For unknown reason, Excel doesn't understand proper ISO 8601 format when retrieving refreshed data from HTML. All datetimes should be passed in `yyyy-MM-dd` / `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` / `HH:mm:ss` formats with correct `mso-number-format` parameter defined in `styles` section (`mso-number-format:"mm\\/dd\\/yyyy"` in my case).

Comment: Excel requires Excel formatting codes ("Custom" format) in `mso-number-format`, and ignores everything else. So that's likely the reason why it didn't understand your formatting instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with numerical formats. Apparently excel does not recognize more than one class for formatting purpose, so if you specify `<td class="cls1 cls2">123</td>` and you have `<style>.cls1 {mso-number-format:"\#\.00"}</style>` – that won't work. You need to use `<td class="cls1">123</td>`, without `cls2`. That was a good enough solution for me, you might also want to try `<td style='mso-number-format:"\#\.00"' class='cls2'>123</td>`, not sure if that'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Style attribute works when you have to use other classes.

Comment: @Pawel Haha I don't even remember how I knew this 9 years ago, but you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I have done this and it works great.

```
    'style to format numbers to string 
    Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"
    Response.Write(style)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
```

you can probably try any number format this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just write formula, like this:

```
=CONVERT("04/12/2019 20:48:21")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to write such a formula every time an Excel file is exported from an external system. My question was not about a single document but rather about a common repetitive case.