# Export html page into excel

Tags: html, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to export html data into excel but I am facing problem with date values as:
I am expecting

```
<pre>"<tr><td style='mso-number-format:d\-mmm\-yyyy'  >Mar-21-2014</td></tr>"</pre>
```

to be 21- Mar-2014

but when I open excel I found it Mar-21-2014 (without change)!!

why does this happen ??

Comment: how are you exporting the data? my guess is that you are simply copying and pasting ...

Comment: I am using html editor and have <tr><td style='mso-number-format:d\-mmm\-yy'  >Mar-21-2014</td></tr>

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not recognise this as a date, probably because your regional settings have DMY order and the text is in MDY order.

After importing the text into Excel, select the column, then click Data > Text To Columns > Next > Next

Now you are in Step 3 of the Text To Columns wizard. Click the Date radio button and in the drop-down next to it select MDY (i.e. the order in the imported text). Then click Finish and all text values will be real dates in your regional setting date order.

Edit after comment:

The mso-number-format does not look quite right. I'm not too familiar with it, but as far as I know the format itself must be in quotes. See [this other Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526055/excel-doesnt-apply-mso-number-format-from-html) for some scenarios

Even if your style tag syntax was correct, you must have the unformatted date in a format that your Excel will normally recognize as a date. If Excel does not recognize it as a date, it will consider the value as text and you cannot format text into a date. You need to start with a date.

Comment: But I am using the style style='mso-number-format:d\-mmm\-yy' inside my html so shouldn't it converted to the correct format ?